# C# ClickOnce application doesn't update

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, clickonce

I have a C# application which I want to publish to an FTP site, and it will automatically update my application from this FTP location. So I run the publish wizard:

1. Specify the location to publish this application:

   ```
   ftp://45.webmasters.com/program/
   ```
2. How will users install the application:
   From a CD or DVD-ROM
   (Not Website nor a [UNC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_%28computing%29#Uniform_Naming_Convention) path accept the FTP)
3. Where should the application check for updates?
   The application will check for updates from the following locations:
   ***I want to update from the FTP site like: ftp://45.webmasters.com/program/***, but this option is only to update the application from a Web site (HTTP).

I abandoned the publish wizard and try to publish from the properties. In Solution Explorer, right-click on the project and click properties and go to Publish tab.

1. Publish folder:
   ftp://45.webmasters.com/program/
2. Installation folder URL (IF DIFFERENT THAN ABOVE).
   So this should be blank since I want to install this from the FTP site. I leave it blank, NO it says it wants to give it an HTTP location. Even that gives you the option to specify an FTP site; it wants a URL.
   Anyway, let's say I add there http: localhost/ just to bypass this box. 
   I choose the application is online and offline in order to enable the updates button. I press the UPDATES button.
3. The application should check for updates is checked.
4. When to check for updates, the radio button before the application starts is selected.
5. Specify a minimum required version is not checked.
6. Update location (if different than publish location).
   So I leave it blank in order to check for updates from the publish location.

And finally I press PUBLISH NOW and the application is published on the FTP site. I go to the FTP site, and I download the application and the application files and I run the application from my desktop and it checks for updates before the application starts, but when I publish newer versions on the FTP site and I run the application shouldn't it download the newer version? It doesn't; it sticks with the old version.

I cannot understand these options.. Is it possible that is not allowed to publish and update from an FTP location?

Comment: This is a duplicate question of this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11095482/i-need-peoples-opinion-on-how-to-update-a-clickonce-app-through-ftp

Comment: This is a duplicate thread of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11095482/i-need-peoples-opinion-on-how-to-update-a-clickonce-app-through-ftp

Comment: This is a duplicate question for this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11095482/i-need-peoples-opinion-on-how-to-update-a-clickonce-app-through-ftp

Comment: this question was whether i can use ftp for the clickonce applicaion. Jasper answered that maybe is not supported and i made another question stating which other options do i have to publish the application since ftp is not supported

Comment: Using FTP to install a ClickOnce app is definitely not supported.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It says it in *[How to: Publish a ClickOnce Application using the Publish Wizard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/31kztyey%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)* that *Direct download from FTP is not supported.* when you publish to 'publish to a file share' - maybe you should choose 'publish to a web' path.